# Cannot convert method group 'QueryFrame' to non-delegate type 'Image<Bgr, byte>' c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, webcam, emgucv

I'm currently creating a windows software that will automatically capture using webcam when using login wrongly 3 times and save the captured photo in the folder. Before this, I have try this code in my VB.net project and it works fine but now I want to do it in C# but it gives me this error.

> Cannot convert method group 'QueryFrame' to non-delegate type
>   'Image'.

```
  Emgu.CV.VideoCapture imagecapture;
        public int timeLeft { get; set; }

        void loadimage()
        {
            try
            {

                if ((Directory.Exists("C:\\USBlocker") == false))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\PutLock");
                }

                Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte> imageviewer = this.imagecapture.QueryFrame ; //THE ERROR IS HERE
                pictureBox1.Image = imageviewer.Bitmap;


                string fileName = "C:\\USBlocker\\A.jpg";
                int count = 0;
            Find:
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    fileName = (("C:\\USBlocker\\A" + Convert.ToString("("))
                                + (count.ToString() + ").jpg"));
                    count++;
                    goto Find;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add your logic here
                    imageviewer.Save(fileName);
                }

                imagecapture.Dispose();
                this.Hide();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timeLeft > 0)
            {
                timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();

                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Webcam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((imagecapture == null))
            {
                try
                {
                    imagecapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }   
       }
```

Comment: On what line of code. That error generally means you are using the name of a function in a place where you really want to call the function (i.e., you're missing parentheses). Look for some place where you are using `MyFunction` instead of `MyFunction()`

Comment: Sorry, just saw the comment. Add some parens after `QueryFrame`

Comment: `this.imagecapture.QueryFrame();`

Comment: I add (); after QueryFram but it gives me this error = Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>'

Comment: That method returns a [Mat](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm)